# angularjs is not working properly

Tags: angularjs

when i clicking signup button it has to go to next page without loading but for me it's get loaded and go to next page here it's my code

```
<div class=login-page> 
<div class=row>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-md-offset-4 col-lg-offset-4"> 
        <img src=images/flat-avatar.png class=user-avatar> 
        <h1>Login form</h1> 
            <form name="product_form" class="form-horizontal" role="form" ng-submit=submit()> 
                <div class=form-content>
                    <div class=form-group mod="product"> 
                        <input type=text class="form-control input-underline input-lg" placeholder=Email name="emailid"  ng-model="product.email" required> 

                     </div> 
                    <div class=form-group mod="product">
                        <input type=password class="form-control input-underline input-lg" placeholder=Password name="password"  ng-model="product.password" required>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <button type=submit class="btn btn-white btn-outline btn-lg btn-rounded">Login</button> 
                <button type=button 
                        class="btn btn-white btn-outline btn-lg btn-rounded"  onclick="document.location='views/Register.html'">Signup</button>
            </form> 
    </div> 
</div>
```

Please help me

Comment: angular works fine, this is wrong `onclick="document.location='views/Register.html'"`

Comment: what should i have to do insetaed of writing onclick

Comment: `it has to go to next page without loading` are you referring to an ajax request? Typically for click events in angular you use `ng-click`, nor should you use `document.location`

Comment: iam referring to ajax request

Comment: ok, so you want to use `ng-click` to call a function in your controller i.e. `ng-click="showSignUpForm()"` and that function could bring up say a modal window with your sign up form. That form then makes an ajax request via `$http`. Search for `angular ng-click` and `angular http`

Comment: shall i use  two ng-submit            <form name="product_form" class="form-horizontal" role="form" ng-submit=submit() ng-submit=button()>

Comment: What? No. I think you need to take a couple angular tutorials. It sounds like you are pretty new to it.

Comment: then what i can do it iam new for angular js please help me

Comment: Take a look at his: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute

Comment: thanks @Mikey   i will learn this thanks for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use ng-click with $location service instead of onClicK().
ng-click() with $location make sure you don't question the server for the page.
onclick') is a basic JS function that actually questions the server for the page.